# What is the node:id cache tag equivalent for blocks?

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I am wondering why the last two entries do not work:

```
public function getCacheTags() {
  $tags = [
    'node:270',
    'node:271',
    'node:273',
    'node:282',
    'block:customblockname',
    'block:7',
  ];
  $cacheTags = Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), $tags);

  return $cacheTags;
}
```

When I edit my custom block the URL is:

> /block/7?destination=/admin/structure/block/block-content

The actual id of the block (for instance when embedding it) is `customblockname`.

What are the correct cache tags to include that block in my caching?

Comment: There is a database table named `cachetags`. Opening that makes me believe blocks are named like this: `config:block.block.bartik_branding` Where bartik_branding is the system name. So I suppose the pattern to be `config:block.block.SYSNAME`. You should however be able to use the `getCacheTags()` method on the block entity. That should always work.

Comment: its actually just `'block_content:7',` :)

Comment: It actually is *both*. block_content:7 is the content entity with the actual data inside. But config:block.block.machine_name is the config entity of the block config entity, which contains placement information (theme, region, weight, settings, ..). What exactly you need depends on what you are doing, you should not have to hardcode your cache tags like that

Answer (score 1):

I just figured myself. The cache tag for custom blocks is simply:

`block_content:7`

Comment: Still I think it would be better to use getCacheTags on the block entity. Seems more solid and future proof.

Comment: @Neograph734 how would you do that?

Comment: For custom blocks you should be able to do something like `$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);` to obtain the block (or maybe you have loaded it already). Then `$block->getCacheTags();` to obtain the cache tag(s).

Comment: @Neograph734 That is pretty the correct answer, which remains valid even if the _Block_ entity defines new cache tags, or third-party modules add more tags.